# Qual arquitetura utilizar para desenvolver Chat em Java?

Tags: java, chat

E ae pessoal,

Seguinte, estou começando um projeto para fazer um chat, um widget na verdade. Ainda está tudo no papel. A ideia é que qualquer sistema ERP consiga implementar este chat... porém estou no inicio, e não tenho nenhum norte de como fazer a arquitetura deste app já que terá que ser algo "dinamico". Vocês tem alguma dica, algum exemplo, algum case de sucesso usando esta linha de pensamento?

Comment: Quado estudei socktes, os exemplo eram relacionados a chat.

Comment: Eu estava lendo, para fazer um chat web, o interessante seria estudar sobre WebSocket, estou dando uma pesquisada no google mesmo, tu tens algum material pra indicar? Quem sabe um livro @Macario1983?

Comment: Este livro `TCP/IP Sockets in Java: Practical Guide for Programmers` é bastante conceituado, pode te ajudar

Comment: Ele não seria web então?

Comment: @LeonardoVillela sim seria um webapp, queria fazer um plugin de comunicação, pra integrar em qualquer webapp